# replace -999.25 on all xlsx sheet cells by 0.01

Tags: replace, openpyxl, xlsx

I have an xlsx sheet called 'Data' in a work book called '1046102004 Analysis.xlsx'
Row 1 contains log names
Row 2 contains log units
Row 3 contains the data
the sheet has the value -999.25 in different rows from 3 (fixed) to max_row and columns from 1 to max_cols
I need to replace -999.25 with 0.01 for subsequent plotting
Any help using python will be highly appreciated

```
fnm ="S:/Python/New folder/1046102004 Analysis.xlsx"
NL = -999.25
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fnm)
ws = wb["Data"]

for row in ws:
        for cell in row:
           if cell.value == NL:
               cell.value = 0.01
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: I have 585 rows and 27 columns

Comment: you can download the xlsx file from the following link    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mHfWrRDq0V1t8IgTGsFal7sMBFcoxoNH/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102856664670041132711&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code and this should work. Note that I have tried to make minimal changes to existing code...

```
fnm ="S:/Python/New folder/1046102004 Analysis.xlsx"
NL = -999.25
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fnm)
ws = wb["Data"]

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=3):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == NL:
            cell.value = 0.01
wb.save(fnm)
```

**Output are program runs**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately it did not work out

Comment: Why not? I ran the code and it updates fine. Let me know what error you are getting or share the file that is not running. Attached screen shot in response

Comment: Thank you Redox so much for your support. It seems though not logic the code can not handel the frequent presence of -999.25 value. In fact the code worked fine on your data and on a too much less frequency of -999.25

Comment: the code does not produce any error meanwhile does not change any cell content. I am new to Stackoverflow and do not know how to attach the file for your review

Comment: How big is the data? In rows? If you can post the data in the question (minimal sample data that the above code will fail), can be tested. Adding table data info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables). But, if is not too big, just paste as text in code snippet as well